# Generalization of Cayley-Hamilton Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

One of the important theorems in linear algebra is the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. As algebraic geometry has linear algebra as a special case in some sense (from linear polynomials to higher degree polynomials), I am wondering whether we can generalize the Cayley-Hamilton theorem in algebraic geometry setting?

Comment: Do you know about Cayley-Hamilton theorem over modules?

Comment: @mathmath Yes, I know C-H holds for endomorphisms of modules.